# How can I decide between passive and active attic venting?

Tags: roof, exhaust-fan

How do you decide which one to install? This is for a 2200 square feet, one-story, 40-year old home in the hot and humid Southeast Texas. During our last roof renovation, many years ago, the contractor replaced the electrical fan with a turbine vent. Now the roof has two turbine vents. I am concerned about inadequate attic ventilation and condensation buildup on the drywall ceiling.

We have replaced the wooden soffit with vented Hardie-board soffit (has many holes in it). The attic has the original fiberglass flooring insulation. Under the shingles there is only a plyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to decide unless you *enjoy* paying for electrical power you don't need. If you need more ventilation, add more in the form of additional turbines or full-length ridge venting.

I don't see the relationship between attic temperature and ceiling moisture, though. Condensation typically comes from moisture *inside* the home, and it condenses on *cool* surfaces. You're dealing with neither of those. If you have enough heat migrating through the attic insulation that *its* surface is cool and condensing, you have an insulation problem, not a venting problem. Or both.